# Meteor autoform remove asterisk form radio option

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have an autoform with `select-radio-inline'` type. the required asterisk shows in all the options. I want to remove it from the radio box.
How to achieve?

[image]

Schema:

```
name: {
  type: String,
  autoform: {
    type: 'select-radio-inline',
    label: "Sex",
    afFieldInput: {
      options: function() {
        return [{
          label: "male",
          value: "male"
        }, {
          label: "female",
          value: "female"
        }];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the asterisk by overwriting the corresponding CSS rule, for example:

```
[data-required] label:after {
    content: '';
}
```

If you want to hide all asterisks for your `name` group only, you could create a `div` which wraps your AutoForm element and then use the `div`'s identifier as a parent selector:

```
#name > [data-required] label:after {
    content: '';
}
```

If you want to keep the asterisk for your label and just remove the asterisks for your radio options within the `name` group, you could use:

```
[data-schema-key="name"] label:after {
    content: '';
}
```

[Read more](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#how-can-i-show-an-asterisk-after-the-label-for-required-fields) about the `data-required` attribute in [Meteor AutoForm](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
.form-group[data-required="true"] .af-radio-group label:after {
    content: "" !important;
}
```